# Missing AVFoundation.framework

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

`AVFoundation.framework` is not where the documentation says it should be. I have iPhone SDK 2.2 installed (never had previous sdk versions installed) and I can't find that folder under `/System/Library/Frameworks`

I did find it under

```
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

folder but if I add it from that location, then the compiler can't find the header files. I tried copying the entire `AVFoundation.framework` folder to `/System/Library/Framework`, but it still can't find the header files.

How can I use `AVFoundation` classes?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Hm, I take it this framework won't work on a OS 2.1 iPhone, right?

Comment: Nope - the framework was only added starting OS 2.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've used the AVFoundation classes in my code, and added it the same way you did. You cannot browse the headers for some unknown reason, but putting this in your classes header file compiles just fine:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
```

I've submitted my app and had it approved, so I don't think there's anything wrong with this approach. The AVFoundation reference remains red in XCode, but it seems to work fine. Deleting the framework reference causes compile errors, so it definitely needs to be there.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer made me realize I was importing AVFoundation.h instead of AVAudioPlayer.h and that was the reason it didn't compile

Comment: in that case you should mark this question as answered, that's how the whole stack overflow thing works. You can also up/down vote my answer depend on whether it's good or not.

Answer (score 7):

I was having all sorts of problem until I realized I have to change the "active executable" to "iPhone Simulator 2.2" too. Here's the steps I took:

Add the `AVFoundation` framework to your project. Ctrl-click on Frameworks folder and select "**Add existing frameworks**". The default framework directory in "`/System/Frameworks`" may not contain the new AVFoundation framework file, so you will need to navigate very deep into the iPhone SDK directory to find the file. I found mine in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.2.sdk/System/Library/Framework`. (Yes, it is that deep!!).

Now from your XCode, select your Active SDK to be "Simulator - iPhone OS 2.2" and select your "Active Executable" to be "iPhone Simulator (2.2)"

That solved the problem for me. Hope yours is the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found mine at:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks