# dyld: Library not loaded: AVFoundation.framework Reason: image not found

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

How do I fix this?

> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation   Referenced from: /Users/[...]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/[...]/TestGame.app/TestGame   Reason: image not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this Framework to Xcode.

Right-click on "Frameworks" > Choose Add > Existing Frameworks
Locate "AVFoundation" then choose Add.

If you want to add it manually, choose the other button and navigate to:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/
```

Replace the iPhone SDK version with whatever you are building against.

Perhaps also see this answer: [Missing AVFoundation.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385530/missing-avfoundation-framework)

Also, sometimes you just need to close Xcode, then clean and rebuild.

Comment: I'd recommend restarting XCode. This problem occurs very often when you switch between Active Configuration (e.g. Debug, Release).

Comment: if you can't get it still run then make that framework optional then you will get application running smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

I'd the same problem, was able to solve it by setting the added frameworks as `Optional` instead of `Required`
 from here, `Project-> Targets-> Build Phases-> Link Binary with Libraries`, change the status of added (or which creating the problem) frameworks to `Optional`, *and it will run successfully.!*