# still dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, ios6

I am integrating Facebook in my application. As required frameworks I added to the project.
But the app crashes without loading even first screen.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/8E09C9AA-CA81-4C26-AEED-B2C632B60A54/Gridlocked.app/Gridlocked
  Reason: image not found
```

I use Xcode 4.5 and my iPad runs iOS 5.1 The app runs fine on the simulator (both 6.0 & 5.1), but when I connect the iPad and change the deployment target to 5.1 (as without this the device is not shown to run), the app crashes.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Found out the solution to the problem.
The problem was setting the added frameworks as **required** instead of **optional**

GO TO Project-> Targets-> Build Phases-> Link Binary with Libraries

There, set the status of added frameworks to **Optional**

This solved my problem.

Comment: @all -> Thanks guys for upvoting. I am glad that my lot of spent hours are helpful to you all.

Comment: Just curious, why does this fix the issue?

Comment: I was using `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` and had to set it to optional . Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may happen because of framework compilation. I worked out it

App target -> Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks.

So mark copy only when installing on. Clean the project and run it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this Framework to Xcode.

Right-click on "Frameworks" > Choose Add > Existing Frameworks
Locate "AVFoundation" then choose Add.

If you want to add it manually, choose the other button and navigate to:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/
```

Replace the iPhone SDK version with whatever you are building against.

Perhaps also see this answer: [Missing AVFoundation.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385530/missing-avfoundation-framework)

Also, sometimes you just need to close Xcode, then clean and rebuild.

also see [dyld: Library not loaded: AVFoundation.framework Reason: image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462964/dyld-library-not-loaded-avfoundation-framework-reason-image-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. i keep all .dylib in system root directory **usr/lib** it working fine. At the run time .o file not get .dylib file path then it gives an error.