# App working in iphone and iPad Simulator but crashing in iPad

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, crash

My App is working fine in the Simulators both iPhone and iPad. But app crashing in iPad at Splash screen, control didn't even reaches DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Here is the crash log i'm receiving through console-

> Mar 14 13:26:45 unknown UIKitApplication:com.beTools.dinoLearns[0x1655][197] : dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/74BD670F-D780-420D-8BFB-107B73798 6B3/PopLetters.app/PopLetters
>
> Mar 14 13:26:45 unknown UIKitApplication:com.beTools.dinoLearns[0x1655][197] : Reason: image not found
>   Mar 14 13:26:45 unknown ReportCrash[196] : Formulating crash report for process PopLetters[197]
>   Mar 14 13:26:45 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.beTools.dinoLearns[0x1655]) Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap: 5

What is wrong here?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915050/still-dyld-library-not-loaded

Comment: Thanks Rich Tolley that worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdSupport frameworks is available from iOS6. So to prevent app crash you can one thing that From the Project **Build Phases** select **Link Binary With Libraries** and Mark **AdSupport** as Optional.

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

Make your AdSupport framework to optional instead of required .it works for me.

Tap on project than go to Targets-> Build Phases-> Link Binary with Libraries

There set status of AdSupport frameworks to Optional(Can be done by tapping the arrow) .