# Where is AVFoundation Framework?

Tags: frameworks

I am beginning a project in audio, for learning purposes, but when i right-clicked on the Frameworks folder and selected "Frameworks", the list did not include the AVFoundationFramework.

Where might it be?, and is the AudioToolbox framework similar?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

John Doner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might this help?

[Missing AVFoundation.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385530/missing-avfoundation-framework)

> "You cannot browse the headers for
>   some unknown reason, but putting this
>   in your classes header file compiles
>   just fine:"
>
> ```
> #import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
> ```